# Macro for sorting of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet which contains a total if 24 columns and several hundred rows. I then used a macro to hide a few columns and to arrange the data in a specific order depending upon the various values in one of the columns (STTN TO). While arranging the data, the macro also inserted the header row data whenever there was a change in the STTN TO value.

After this I used another macro which arranged the data within each data group formed as per the STTN TO value as per the order of CMDT specified in the code. This code is working fine but is removing the header labels between the STTN TO values that existed between data groups prior to running this code and pasting it towards the end of the worksheet.

I have near to zero experience in VBA or programming for that matter and took the help of ChatGPT till here but really stuck now. The VBA code for the second macro is given below

```vb
Sub SortDataWithinDataGroup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim customSortOrderCMDT As Variant
        
    customSortOrderCMDT = Array("IMCL", "STC", "PBC", "PHC", "NPHC", "IOST", "IORE", "LSST", "LST", "DLMT", "DLST", "IS", "PIOR", "METL", "SAND", "NCOL", "STON", "FOIL", "SLPR", "MIXD")
        
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("I1:I" & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=Join(customSortOrderCMDT, ","), DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("P1:P" & lastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=Join(customSortOrderCMDT, ","), DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange ws.UsedRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

The expected output is that the data group within the individual values of STTN TO gets sorted on the basis of commodities in the order mentioned in the array but without removing the data headers present in between the data groups. However, the header labels are getting removed and getting pasted to the bottom of the worksheet

Comment: I just recorded a macro doing a sort with header and in the macro,  Key:=Range("A2:...") while the .SetRange = Range(A1:...).  You have to remove the header row from the key.

Comment: Try changing this `"I1:I" & lastRow` part to this `"I2:I" & lastRow`. So sorting is only applied starting at row2. Same with the other part `"P2:P" & lastRow`.

Comment: You cannot sort a range with multiple header rows for "subgroups". In this case every subgroup has to be  sorted individually.

Comment: Why not add the subgroup headers *after* the sort?